# How to ADD for loop result in templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

views.html

```
{% for products in product %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ products.quantity_deliver1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ products.quantity_deliver2 }}</td>
    <td>{{ Code Here }}</td>

</tr>
{% empty %}
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" class="text-center bg-warning">No Products</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I add `products.quantity_deliver1 + products.quantity_deliver2` and output the sum in the 3rd data cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use builtin django template tag `add` for adding two.

```
{{products.quantity_deliver1|add:products.quantity_deliver2}}
```

Ref - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add